# Tangent plane and normals in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function given by
$$z = f(x, y) = x^4 + y^4.$$
Find the point on the surface $z = f(x, y)$, where the normal to the surface is perpendicular to the chord joining the points $(0, 0, f(0, 0))$ and $(1, 1, f(1, 1))$.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Yea. I took the normal vector to the level surface z - x^4 -y^4 = 0 and then I took dot product with the chord vector. This gave me a relation. I need one more to solve.

Answer (score 0):

By definition the normal to a surface (in $\mathbb{R}^3$) is the (affine) line ortogonal to the tangent (affine) plane to the surface.

Now it's easy to conclude:

- Find the generic equation (in function of $x$ and $y$) of the **affine** plane $TS_{(x,y,f(x,y))}$ tangent to the surface in $(x,y,f(x,y))$
- Impose that the line through the points $(0,0,f(0,0))$ and $(1,1,f(1,1))$ is conteined in $TS_{(x,y,f(x,y))}$
- Solve the system of equations and find the opportune values of $x$, $y$ and $z$

Comment: I don't know what is affine plane and opportunes value. I have only read Thomas Calculus.

Comment: Very often the tangent plane to the graph of a function in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is definited as the "vector space generated by the column of Jacobian". 
To consider It as the plane passing through a point $P$ of the graph you have to translate it in $P$, so it is an affine plane!